# Como obtener solo algunas Columnas DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Buen día, tengo este Web Service que me proporciona todos los datos de una tabla y todas las columnas, ¿Cómo selecciono sólo algunas Columnas y no todas?

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable consultaIndividualSUCIS(int tipoCodigoEntidad, int estadoAutorizacion)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE tipoCodigoEntidad = @tipoCodigoEntidad AND estadoAutorizacion = @estadoAutorizacion"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipoCodigoEntidad", tipoCodigoEntidad);  // <-- Este es el parámetro de SQL que estás recibiendo cómo parámetro en tu método
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estadoAutorizacion", estadoAutorizacion);  // <-- Este es el parámetro de SQL que estás recibiendo cómo parámetro en tu método

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        dt.TableName = "Idoneidad_Funcionarios";

                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

la tabla es la siguiente:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|tipCod   | Nombre    |estadoAut  |fechaInicio |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|101      |Pepe       |Activo     |2017/05/01  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

En los resultados solo quiero obtener y que el Parámetro de búsqueda sea [tipCod]:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| Nombre    |estadoAut  |fechaInicio |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|Pepe       |Activo     |2017/05/01  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: SELECT Nombre, estadoAut,fechaInicio FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE tipoCodigoEntidad = tipoCodigoEntidad AND estadoAutorizacion = estadoAutorizacion AND tipCod=tipCod"))
            {

Comment: Compadre Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu valioso tiempo.
XD como fui de tonto y no me di cuenta que lo que necesito es un simple Query o modificar el Query de SQL, la verdad No me fijé.

Comment: De nada amigo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Nombre, 
       estadoAut,
       fechaInicio
  FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios 
 WHERE tipoCodigoEntidad = @tipoCodigoEntidad
   AND estadoAutorizacion = @estadoAutorizacion
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una descripción para explicar cómo es que esto responde a la pregunta?

Comment: Claro, en mi consulta pregunto como seleccionar algunas columnas y no todas, pues en el Query tengo especificado que:
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE (...) 
Cuando el compadre Rastalovely me dice que haga un (SELECT Nombre, EstadAut,  fechaInicio (...)) pues me di cuenta de que todo estaba en la Query de SQL y no lo pensé,

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes,

lo que debes hacer es modificar la sentencia del sqlcommand para que solo traiga las columnas que necesitas.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre,estadoAut,fechaInicio FROM Idoneidad_Funcionarios WHERE tipoCodigoEntidad = @tipoCodigoEntidad AND estadoAutorizacion = @estadoAutorizacion"))
```